# How do I access a window on another screen using Awesome?

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, awesome-wm

I have two monitors. How can I focus on a window that is on a different screen than the one I'm working on?

<kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>h</kbd> works only for one monitor.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Superuser! We'd need more information to be able to answer your question - what operating system or application are you talking about?

Comment: Though a different approach but given you're on linux or mac you can use `rofi` in the `window` mode. Anyway it is useful when you have more than two workspaces active IMHO.

Answer (score 13):

`awesome` refers to different monitors as `screens` just as you do. Check the man page for commands mentioning `screen`. Here are some helpful ones:

1. `Mod4 + Control + j` focus next screen

   - this moves your cursor from one screen to another. it changes the focus from a client window on one screen to a client window on the next screen.
2. `Mod4 + o` send client to next screen

   - this moves a client window to the next screen!

So to answer your question, you will probably need to first `Mod4 + Control + j` to the next screen, and then `Mod4 + j` through the clients on that screen/tag until the one you want is in focus.

Comment: Hi, I'm also having the same problem. I know that I have to switch the screen first. But you need to change shortcut. I've found https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52794/267510 which could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure the keys in `.config/awesome/rc.lua`.

The default binding `Mod4 + o` only moves a client to the screen on the right. You can also add a keybinding to move to the left.

In the following example, I mapped `Mod4 + Control + [j|k]` to move the focus to the screen left/right. And if you also hold down the `Shift` key then it also moves the currently focused window along with it.

```lua
globalkeys = gears.table.join(

    -- ...

    awful.key({ modkey, "Control" }, "j",
                function () awful.screen.focus_relative( 1) end,
                {description = "focus the next screen", group = "screen"}),


    awful.key({ modkey, "Control" }, "k",
                function () awful.screen.focus_relative(-1) end,
                {description = "focus the previous screen", group = "screen"}),

    -- ...

)

clientkeys = gears.table.join(

    -- ...

    awful.key({ modkey, "Control", "Shift" }, "k",
                function (c) c:move_to_screen(c.screen.index - 1) end,
                {description = "move to screen left", group = "client"}),

    awful.key({ modkey, "Control", "Shift" }, "j",
                function (c) c:move_to_screen(c.screen.index + 1) end,
                {description = "move to screen right", group = "client"}),

    -- ...

)
```